# How to Run Python programs from client end in IBM WATSON CHAT BOT

Tags: python, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

My requirement:

My requirement is to develop a chat bot using IBM WATSON but i am not able to understand how can i run python programs from client end (not in IBM CLOUD) and i have to take all the parameters bot collected for a particular API call and pass all these values to python programs that are running on client end and collect response from programs and populate it through bot.

The above is my requirement and following are the questions i have:

1) How can i run python programs in client end and what are the necessary steps required (They does not want to run their API calls in IBM cloud due to data privacy )

2) How can i pass parameters i collected from BOT to programs running on client machine.

3) How can i populate response collected from client end through bot .

4) what are the changes i have to made in IBM WATSON to achieve all the above.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Thanks your understanding is correct but I did not get last paragraph can you please elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your questions, so forgive me if I have understood incorrectly. You wish to run a python program on a local machine (say windows pc), and have that program use IBM's Watson. You can run your python application on your machine, which then makes a RESTful call to the Watson API. You could use the python "requests" package to perform such an action. The following links to the [Doc for Watson Assistant API calls](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1), you can use either [V1.0](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1) or [V2.0](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2) of the API calls, and expect the individual API call you wish is the message API. 
Again normally the Watson Assistant service is cloud based, even if you code is local on you machine/server. You can however for customers get a in house instance of Watson, but service is not cheap.

Comment: With regards to passing parameters to Watson Assistant, these can be included as part of the question to the message, API, or part of the context. 
I would recommend you try one of the on line tutorials.